# a sortable list that comes from database

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, jquery-ui

I have a simple list in html:

```
<ul id="sortable">
    <li id="1">item1</li>
    <li id="2">item2</li>
    <li id="3">item3</li>
</ul>
```

I make it sortable with jQuery UI. This lets the user move the order of each item:

```
$('#sortable').sortable();
```

But when I get the same items from a MySql database the "sortable" doesn't work any more I cannot change the order of the items. So my question is: how to make a list sortable when the list comes from a database?

```
<?php  
$result = mysqli_query($con, 'SELECT * FROM principal ORDER BY ordre');
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
?>

<ul id="sortable">
    <li id="<?php echo $row["id"] ?>"><?php echo $row["concepte"]?>;</li>
</ul>
<?php
```

Comment: What does the HTML generated by the PHP look like?

Comment: Do you have any Javascript error?

Comment: Define "doesn't work". What happens that shouldn't happen? What doesn't happen that should? What errors are displayed on the console. What happens if you test `$('#sortable').length` just before you try to call `sortable` on it?

Comment: @Quentin: in the browser I can see the list that I have in the database well reproduced

Comment: Does not work means that I cannot sort the items, I mean I cannot change the order of the items

Comment: I'm sure that there are examples out there of sortable used with a database

Comment: @Dimitar: I have the DOM ready. The example without the php works well

Comment: @Nrc — Don't just describe it, show us.

Comment: Coming from a database makes no difference to the client. HTML is HTML, it doesn't matter if it was generated by hand or by software (so showing us the PHP that generates the HTML instead of the HTML isn't all that helpful). Something else about the page must have changed.

Comment: @Quentin: how can I show it? I think JSFiddle does not work with jQuery UI and php. Is there any other way?

Comment: @Nrc — You go to the View menu in your browser, then Source, then you copy and paste from it.

Comment: @Quenting: that is true I should have gone to the source first. Sorry, I am just learning

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are generating ul elements for each record row, where as it should be one single UL having multiple LI elements, also fix the li HTML code

```
<?php  
$result = mysqli_query($con, 'SELECT * FROM principal ORDER BY ordre');
echo '<ul id="sortable">';
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
?>


    <li id="<?php echo $row["id"]; ?>"><?php echo $row["concepte"]; ?></li>
<?php 
   }
echo '</ul>';
?>
```

Comment: Good spot. (And something that would be been much more obvious if we'd been looking at the HTML instead of the PHP).

Comment: Yes, this solves the problem. Can you explain me why I have negative points? what should I do better?

Comment: @Nrc I am not sure why but most likely that's a very basic question which can easily find by looking up before posting, or do google. I have no idea how this works as of yet

Answer (score 1):

I'm not a PHP guy but this looks like it's going to generate a `ul` with each iteration ? So your markup would be all screwed up